# OpenCVでThread*:signalSIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, opencv

OpenCVで画像処理を行っていると、上記のThread*:signal SIGABRT(*は１以外の数値)でエラーが吐き出されます。
画像処理中に形状認証用の配列に数値を加算し続ける、という処理を入れるとほぼ確実に起こり、その一文をコメントアウトすると解消されます。しかし、求めるプログラムにはその一文が不可欠です。

signalSIGABRTは単純なミスが問題と聞きますが、ストーリーボードのリンクミスの確認やプロダクトのクリーンを行っても問題が解消されず、調べてもThread1ばかりで解決できませんでした。

お心当たりがありましたらご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 言語はObjective-C、Xcodeはバージョン8.1、iOS10向けに開発しています

Comment: 「配列に数値を加算し続ける」の処理で配列のサイズが大きくなることはないですか？メモリが配列に使われていって、フリーメモリの残量が少なくなると異常が起きる場合があります。

Comment: 試しに配列を一つ追加したところ、動作するようになりました。ご協力感謝いたします